# Как одной кнопкой вывести результат в консоль из двух разных форм в react

Tags: reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста, в моём react проекте содержится один родитель App(), который возвращает три отрендеренные child компоненты в браузер. В двух компонентах содержатся формы, в третьем кнопка. Как можно пробросить компонент с кнопкой к родителю, чтобы отобразить в консоль результат форм двух других соседних child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Подъём состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - часто несколько компонентов должны отражать одни и те же изменяющиеся данные. Реакт рекомендует поднимать общее состояние до ближайшего общего предка.